# Image not displaying XAML android

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I am trying xamarin forms for the first time so that I can build my app fro android and Iphone

I need to add an image to my layout `MainPage.xaml` and have this layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ReassuredMobileApp"
         x:Class="ReassuredMobileApp.MainPage">

<StackLayout
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout
        VerticalOptions="Start"
        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
        AutomationId="TitleBar">

        <Label
            Text="Hello, world!"></Label>

        <Image
            WidthRequest="200"
            HeightRequest="50"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Source="reassured_text.png" />



    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

But the image `"reassured_text.png"` is not being displayed when I run the app in the emulator. I can see the `Hello, World!` text just fine (still cant see the image when I remove this)

My image is under my project as "reassured_text.png"

I've tried to follow tutorials online, but don't understand what is being said, and the ones I could understand didn't work. I've also tried to format the tag like

```
<Image
    ####Stuff here>

</Image>
```

but that didn't have an effect.

Directory tree:

```
Solution 'MyApp'
    c# - MyApp
        Dependencies
        App.xaml
            App.xaml.cs
        MainPage.xaml
            MainPage.xaml.cs
        reassured_text.png
    MyApp.Android
        drawable
            reassured_text.png
        drawable-hdpi
        drawable-xhdpi
        drawable-xxhdpi
        layout
        values
    MyApp.Ios
        //I haven't touched anything here
```

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/

Comment: @SushiHangover I tried all the methods in that link and none worked. I don't want to add the image through cs, just in the xaml

Comment: @HarveyFletcher Re-read the "Local Images" section:  https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images/#Local_Images

Comment: I have added the image, and followed the instruction, but it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Try setting the `Aspect` to `Fill` on the `Image` tag. Maybe 200x50 isn't enough space to show it. Like this: `<Image Aspect="Fill" (... your stuff ...)/>`

Comment: Try to set bigger HeightRequest

Comment: If the image is in your Android drawable folder and your iOS resource folder and it's still not showing up delete the app from your simulator, delete your bin/obj folders, and rebuild your solution before your next deploy.

Comment: None of these solutions work.

Answer (score 0):

1.Put the image reassured_text.png in Android project i.e in Resource/Drawable folder.

or

2.Put the image reassured_text.png in portable project & set build action to "Embedded Resource" & in .cs file do like this:

imagecontrol.FromResource="reassured_text.png";